# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Authentication NOT Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to implement authentication using Identity into my ASP.NET Core 2.0 project and it doesn't seem to be working. The last project I implement Identity into was an ASP.NET MVC 5 project, and things have changed substantially. I've skipped Core 1.0 and 1.1, so I have no knowledge of how it was done under those, though from what I'm reading it's supposed to be mostly similar.

I can't get it work for me though. When I say it's not working, I mean that I'm not being redirected to a login page even though I'm not authorized.

The only customization I've done is to implement my own user store and my own extension to add identity without the need for a role, since I'm not going to be using roles. I could use some direction on what I'm messing up because from my point of view everything is now way too complicated. Here's the code I've got so far:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(
    IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddDbContext<CustomDbContext>();
    services.AddTransient<IUserStore<GlobalUser>, CustomUserStore<GlobalUser>>();
    services.AddIdentity<GlobalUser>();
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app,
    IHostingEnvironment env) {
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    } else {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

**ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs**

I just looked at the source for the built in `AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>` and omitted the role related stuff, so there shouldn't be an issue with it here, though maybe...

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions {
    public static IdentityBuilder AddIdentity<TUser>(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        Action<IdentityOptions> optionsAction = null)
        where TUser : class {
        services.AddAuthentication(
            o => {
                o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                o.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                o.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            }).AddCookie(
            o => {
                o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login");
                o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents {
                    OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync
                };
            });

        services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IUserValidator<TUser>, UserValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordValidator<TUser>, PasswordValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordHasher<TUser>, PasswordHasher<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IdentityErrorDescriber>();
        services.TryAddScoped<ISecurityStampValidator, SecurityStampValidator<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<UserManager<TUser>, AspNetUserManager<TUser>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<SignInManager<TUser>, SignInManager<TUser>>();

        if (optionsAction != null) {
            services.Configure(optionsAction);
        }

        return new IdentityBuilder(typeof(TUser), services);
    }
}
```

I thought I had to add the Authorize filter like in MVC 5, but I can't seem to do it globally. When I apply it to the default controller, I get the following exception:

> No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no
>   DefaultChallengeScheme found.

But I thought I was setting the scheme in my custom `AddIdentity` method? I could use some guidance and I appreciate any being sent my way.

Comment: Did you pass the scheme in as a part of the Authorize attribute in the controller? Like this: `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)]`, or something like that? I don't know if `IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme` is the enum you need.

Comment: So, I hardcoded "Identity.Application" as the scheme as you suggested, and now the exception changed to `No authentication handler is configured to authenticate for the scheme: Identity.Application`. I'm having a hard time with these schemes. What would be the proper way of just telling ASP.NET that I want cookie authentication with Identity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, and it was me overlooking something when I was making my own `AddIdentity` extension. I was supposed to pass in the `IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme` as a parameter to `AddCookie` *before* passing in the options. I was double checking the Identity source and saw I was missing that. As soon as I added it, everything worked. So:

```
//           ▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼ this is what was missing
}).AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
o => {
```

This was ultimately a problem of my own making...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. I had to implement custom auth based on `FormsAuthentication` cookie, which does not exist in .net core, we have some ASP.Net systems that use `FormsAuthentication` and we need interop. The way that I solved it was to subclass `AuthorizeFilter` and then `override` `OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)`. This is what I cam up with:

```
public class AuthFilter : AuthorizeFilter
{

    public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.Filters.Any(item => item is IAsyncAuthorizationFilter && item != this || item is IAllowAnonymousFilter))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        if (!context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        return base.OnAuthorizationAsync(context);
    }

}
```

Then you have to go register that in `Startup.cs` in `ConfigureServices` i.e.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthFilter(
        new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build()));
});
```

This will be default make ALL your Controllers need authorization. If you need anonymous login, go add `[AllowAnonymous]` to your Controller

Comment: Since all my controllers inherit from a `ControllerBase` class, I've applied the attribute to it, but it's now throwing other exceptions about not finding a registered handler for the scheme.